# Sharing an image using Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, share

I’ve created a Xamarin Forms (PCL) solution, and I’m focusing on the Android project at the moment. I’m trying to implement image sharing using a dependency service. The images are located in the drawable folder of the Android project. However, every time I run the code below, the app crashes with: an unhandled exception occurred. I've checked the output log but nothing stands out. Would anyone be able to run an eye over my code and tell me if there is an error in it?

Many thanks

**Interface:**

```
public interface IShare
{
    void Share(ImageSource imageSource);
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Image x:Name="LogoImage" Source="icon.png"/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
private void Action_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IShare>().Share(LogoImage.Source);
}
```

**ShareClass (in Android project):**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ShareClass))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class ShareClass : Activity, IShare
    {
        public async void Share(ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
            intent.SetType("image/png");

            var handler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
            var bitmap = await handler.LoadImageAsync(imageSource, this);

            var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads
                + Java.IO.File.Separator + "logo.png");

            using (var os = new System.IO.FileStream(path.AbsolutePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
            }

            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(path));
            Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Share Image"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code in the debugger to determine which line is causing the crash?

Comment: @Jason Not done that specifically, but I tried commenting out the using statement in ShareClass.cs. When I did this, the share UI popped up and the image could be shared to other apps like OneDrive (however, the image could not be opened in OneDrive, maybe because it was not compressed properly?). Based on this, I suspect the using statement is causing the problem.

Comment: then have you tried wrapping it in a try/catch to catch the Exception?

Comment: Yeah, try/catch confirms the problem is with the using statement. Do you reckon it could be something to do with the mixing of System.IO and Java.IO in ShareClass.cs? Apart from that, I'm all out of ideas, not sure how to solve this.

Comment: what Exception are you getting?

Comment: I'm surprised you can create an Activity using the DependencyService since you can't `new Activity()` in Java. If you are just using it as a Context for the LoadImageAsync call, you could try removing it from your ShareClass inheritance list and use Forms.Context instead.

Comment: The exception I'm getting is System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/sdcard/Download/logo.png".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I used for the ShareClass to get the sharing intent working in the end, hope it helps someone:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ShareClass))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
public class ShareClass: MainActivity, IShare
{
    public async void Share(ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

        intent.SetType("image/jpeg");

        IImageSourceHandler handler;

        if (imageSource is FileImageSource)
        {
            handler = new FileImageSourceHandler();
        }
        else if (imageSource is StreamImageSource)
        {
            handler = new StreamImagesourceHandler(); // sic
        }
        else if (imageSource is UriImageSource)
        {
            handler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler(); // sic
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        var bitmap = await handler.LoadImageAsync(imageSource, CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);

        Java.IO.File path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads
            + Java.IO.File.Separator + "MyDiagram.jpg");

        using (System.IO.FileStream os = new System.IO.FileStream(path.AbsolutePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, os);
        }

        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, FileProvider.GetUriForFile(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, "com.mypackagename.fileprovider", path));

        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You first need to add permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

#### Xamarin.Android

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(ShareClass))]
namespace ShareDemo.Droid
{
    public class ShareClass : Activity, IShare
    {
        public async void Share(string subject, string message, ImageSource image)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
            //intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, subject);
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, message);
            intent.SetType("image/png");

            ImageLoaderSourceHandler handler = new 
            ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
            Bitmap bitmap = await handler.LoadImageAsync(image, this);

            Java.IO.File path = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads + Java.IO.File.Separator + "logo.png");

            using (System.IO.FileStream os = new System.IO.FileStream(path.AbsolutePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
            }

            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(path));
            Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Xamarin.iOS

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ShareClass))]
namespace ShareSample.iOS
{
    public class ShareClass : IShare
    {
        public async void Share(string subject, string message, ImageSource image)
        {
            var handler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
            var uiImage = await handler.LoadImageAsync(image);
            var img = NSObject.FromObject(uiImage);
            var mess = NSObject.FromObject(message);
            var activityItems = new[] { mess, img };
            var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null);
            var topController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

            while (topController.PresentedViewController != null)
            {
                topController = topController.PresentedViewController;
            }

            topController.PresentViewController(activityController, true, () => { });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Venkata Swamy Balaraju, but I forgot to say that I'd already added the permissions to AndroidManifest.xml in my original post. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: ios 9.3.5 = crash: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController: 0x13ed0d8f0>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use for Android Implementation

```
 public Task Share(string url)
        {
            var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Temp");

            if (!File.Exists(path.Path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path.Path);
            }

            string absPath = path.Path + "tempfile.jpg";
            File.WriteAllBytes(absPath, GetBytes(url));

            var _context = Android.App.Application.Context;

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(global::Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);

            sendIntent.PutExtra(global::Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "Application Name");

            sendIntent.SetType("image/*");

            sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + absPath));
            _context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sendIntent, "Sharing"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public static byte[] GetBytes(string url)
        {
            byte[] arry;
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                arry = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            }
            return arry;
        }
```

As my **targetSdkVersion >24**, I add the following two lines to **MainActivity.cs** to allow other apps to access files.

```
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(builder.Build());
```

And here are the permissions required to be allowed in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```