# How to share a photo from gallery to xamarin app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a way to share a photo from the gallery using the "forward to" function and make my xamarin app appear among those available as whatapp or instagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android) to achieve this.

The `Share` class enables an application to share data such as text and web links to other applications on the device.

Xamarin.Essentials will automatically detect the file type (`MIME`) and request a share. Each platform may only support specific file extensions.

Here is a sample of writing text to disk and sharing it to other apps:

```
var fn =  "Attachment.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = Title,
    File = new ShareFile(file)
});
```

For more,you can check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android .
https://github.com/harshitgindra/ImageShare.Xamarin

And there is similar threads about this, you can check them here:

[Sharing an image using Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230026/sharing-an-image-using-xamarin-forms)